# How do I skip non-matches in perl sed-like find/replace command?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Given this simple sed command:

```
echo "abc\nxyz" | sed "s/abc/***/"
```

The equivalent Perl version is

```
echo "abc\nxyz" | perl -pe "s/abc/***/"
```

Sed lets me only output matching lines like this:

```
echo "abc\nxyz" | sed -n "s/abc/***/p"
```

How do I do that with Perl?

FYI, I want to use Perl's regex engine, which seems more full featured than sed, but I want this sed option.

Comment: Try [`super-sed`](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Super-sed). `sed` from the outside, `perl` from the inside!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl the `-p` switch sets up an implicit loop that iterates over the input, and prints the content of `$_` after each iteration of the loop.  Perl also has the `-n` switch that requires that the code within this implicit loop handle its own output:

`echo "abc\nxyz" | perl -ne 's/abc/***/ && print'`

The `-p` and `-n` switches are described in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

In short, `-p` forms an implicit loop that looks something like this:

```
while( <> ) {
    # Your code goes here...
}
continue {
    print;
}
```

And `-n` forms an implicit loop that looks something like this:

```
while( <> ) {
    # Your code goes here....
}
```

So with `-n`, you must explicitly specify when to produce output, and what that output should be.  By regaining control over the output, you're able to incorporate logic that allows the 'print' to happen only when certain conditions are met, such as the regex matching.  In my example, we're using logical short circuit to trigger print if the match succeeds.

Comment: That is a poor representation of `perl -p`, which reads the input file(s) line by line and `print`s them whether or not they are modified by the code. *"print the outcome of each tranformation that takes place"* is just wrong.

Comment: @Borodin Clarified the first two sentences.

Answer (score 3):

The `-p` option to Perl implies doing the actions of the `-e ...` on each line of the input, then printing. Changing to a `-n` means read each line of the file and do the `-e ...` on each. So a simple way of achieving waht you want is as follows:

```
echo "abc\nxyz" | perl -ne "print if s/abc/***/"
```

Comment: thanks! This answer works too but I can only accept one.